# Why does my program crash from an exception even though I catch that exception type?

Tags: c++, exception

I have this code:

```
printf("hello\n");
try
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < par.size(); i++ )
        rep.delete_rev(par[i]);
}
catch(TriedToDeleteRoot e)
{
    printf("catched 1 !\n");
}
catch(...) {
    printf("catched sth else !\n");
}
printf("hahaha\n");
```

and this is what i have on output:

```
hello
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'TriedToDeleteRoot'
  what():  Tried to delete root
```

why? TriedToDeleteRoot inherits from std::exception, and I don't have any idea what's wrong. Thanks.

EDIT:
this is how I throw an exception:

```
throw TriedToDeleteRoot();
```

Comment: Your code needs to live in a function. Can you post the implementation of `delete_rev` and the definition of whatever type `rep` has.

Comment: possibly getting thrown from somewhere else in the code we can't see? Can you show a *minimal* but complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's possible you're throwing a second exception whilst still handling a previous one. That would be *bad* and IIRC is supposed to call `std::terminate` regardless of what exceptions are handled by a catch block - it seems to be getting called here.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is the copy constructor for TriedToDeleteRoot is failing.

I suggest (as always) catching by const reference:

```
try
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < par.size(); i++ )
        rep.delete_rev(par[i]);
}
catch(const TriedToDeleteRoot& e)
{
    printf("caught 1 !\n");
}
```

or in the general case:

```
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're observing that `std::terminate` is being called even though you have a `try`/`catch` that you expect to match the exception that's being thrown.

One reason this might happen is if you've managed to throw an exception whilst a previous exception is being handled. You can observe this with:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   try {
     struct test {
       ~test() { throw 0; }
     } test;
     throw 0;
   }
   catch (...) {
     std::cout << "Caught something" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

On my system this calls `abort()` and prints:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

Notice that the `catch(...)` never gets hit because of this.

This simple example illustrates the easiest way to accidentally make that happen - [throwing from within a destructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9). My best guess from what you've shown is that this is what's happening. A debugger ought to confirm this for you though.

Comment: +1. Thanks for making this an answer. Moral: never allow a destructor to emit an exception.